# WriteableBitmap inside Windows 10 IBackgroundTask

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am trying to crop an image from a Run method from Windows 10 app (UWP) IBackgroundTask.
To achive that I'm using the WriteableBitmapEx but at the moment that I try to instantiate a new object, I got the exception:

> The application called an interface that was marshalled for a
>   different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E
>   (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

I have tried to use some Dispatchers but other exception ocurred.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WriteableBitmap` is a UI object, and requires UI thread, which background task lacks of.

Depending on your needs, you can either use different API to work with images (check [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt244351.aspx) for `BitmapEncoder`) or derive your background task from [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.xamlrenderingbackgroundtask.aspx), which will call its OnRun method in UI thread. Although keep in mind, that it's recommended to use C++ in XamlRenderingBackgroundTask due to memory limitations.

Comment: Glad I could help. I'd appreciate if you accept the answer though :) Thanks.