# Creating instance of BitmapImage throws exception (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)

Tags: c#, multithreading, bitmapimage

I'm trying to create an instance of `BitmapImage` in a method called `IsImageValid`. When doing so, I get this exception:

> the application called an interface that was marshalled for a
>   different thread. (exception from hresult: 0x8001010e
>   (rpc_e_wrong_thread))

This is my code:

```
public bool isImageValid(string imagePath)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
            var image = new BitmapImage(); // Exception is thrown here!
            //BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.ImageFailed += (s, e) => image.UriSource = new Uri(String.Empty);
            image.UriSource = new Uri(path + @"\" + imagePath);

            if (image != null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
```

I am new to threads and I don't understand why I can't create an instance here. What is the problem?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35090678/writeablebitmap-inside-windows-10-ibackgroundtask